# Iteration over a list on Ruby with i and k values

Tags: ruby, loops, iteration, each

I couldn't find an elegant solution to this code in ruby. Basically what ı wanted to do was this in means of c++

```
for (int i=0;i<list.length;i++)
  {for(int k= i+1; k<list.length; k++)
    {cout<< list[i]<<" "<<list[k]}}
```

But unfortunately I could not find an elegant way to do this in ruby. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

mudasobwa's answer is a relatively literal translation, but it's more idiomatic to use the dedicated method, [`Array#combination`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-combination):

```
list.combination(2) do |el1, el2|
  puts "#{el1} #{el2}"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The code below is untested, but it should work.

```
list.each_with_index do |el1, idx|
  list.drop(idx+1).each do |el2|
    print [el1, el2].join(" ")
  end
end
```

This is an exact line-to-line translation of your [cpp](/questions/tagged/cpp) code to ruby.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev damn, I have everything [tag:c]-related forgotten with these your magic scripting crap.